# I am trying to figure out how to get the proper results from a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out how to get the proper results from a MySQL database.

Table Structure:  **items**

```
PN1            PN2
------------   ------------
702866-001     702866-001
738975-001     702866-001
B9C84AV        702866-001
LMT-256M6M     702866-001
```

The 2nd part # is a cross reference to the master item (PN1), the master item will have PN1 and PN2 duplicated.

The Select statement I needs is that I can search by any part # from either field (PN1 or PN2) and get a complete list of Distinct PN's

For example:  If I search for B9C84AV it would return all Part #'s in PN1 list since they are crossed in PN2.

Basically, what I need is a way to get PN2 for the record where PN1 is equal to the search parameter and then return a Distinct list of all records where PN1 or PN2 = PN2 (returned from the search parameter)

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Bryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather simple:

```
SELECT i.pn1 AS pn,
       CASE WHEN i.pn1 = i.pn2 THEN 'master' ELSE 'item' END AS type
FROM items AS i
  JOIN items AS s
    ON s.pn2 = i.pn2
WHERE s.pn1 = @searhed_PN ;
```

Comment: It worked perfectly.  Thank you so much, I can see the logic in the SQL now, not sure why this has eluded me for so many hours.  Again, thanks so much.